# No Audio in Android Lollipop with pjsip library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, pjsip

My android application uses pjsip library for voice calls, but it is not working on Android 5.x (no audio heard in either direction).
Whenever I place a call, no audio is heard. I am not sure if this is related to audio settings in android in the upgraded version.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Sonal

Answer (score 0):

I am having this exact same issue with my project. The solution I found is to define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ANDROID_JNI to 0 and PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_OPENSL to 1 in the config files.

This brought up a deadlocking issue with OpenSL however (mentioned here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#opensl).

So I'm hoping for a real solution on PJSIP's or Android's side.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the RxLevel() helped me. (Receive level)

```
Media m = getMedia(i);  
AudioMedia am = AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(m);   
am.adjustRxLevel(1.5f);
```

Comment: Where can you find the method?